# Создание сложных структур radio button HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Проблема, как сделать так чтоб при выборе одного radio button появлялось несколько других связаных с ним кнопок. Пример: пользователь выбирает на сайте radio-button категория товара и в зависимости от его выбора появляеться несколько radio button подкатегории товара.

Comment: Что не получилось у вас? Покажите ваши попытки реализации

Comment: Обыгрывайте логику с помощью `js` (оперируя стилями `css` для скрытия/появления блоков, которые пользователь должен увидеть пойдя по той или иной ветке развития событий)